# Javascript not pulling php variables, page not loading php?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I have a site online to test and edit using "000webhost.com" which has php and mysql.

Either javascript is not pulling the PHP variables or the site is not loading php.

when I load the page I start up chrome code viewer to check the code live. when looking over the default.php (index page) it does not show my php variables.

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
var iso = "<?= $isop; ?>";
var meg = "<?= $megp; ?>";
var mex = "<?= $mexp; ?>";
var mor = "<?= $morp; ?>";
var noc = "<?= $nocp; ?>";
var pye = "<?= $pyep; ?>";
var tri = "<?= $trip; ?>";
var zyd = "<?= $zydp; ?>";
}
```

php page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Str8nge Brew Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$isop = "1";
$megp = "1";
$mexp = "1";
$morp = "1";
$nocp = "1";
$pyep = "1";
$trip = "1";
$zydp = "1";
?> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="calceve.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
....
</body>
```

Comment: Does your PHP configuration have short-open tags enabled? Is your Javascript in a PHP script (.php) or in a .js file?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Also, `iso` will be local only to the `onload` callback of `window`, so you can't use it anywhere else.

Comment: where is the window.onload code? in calceve.js?

Comment: is the js code you mention in ´calceve.js´?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your calceve.js file to render the PHP contained within, you'll need to change the file extension to .php, `src="calceve.php"`.  Whenever I have a javascript file that contains PHP, I use something like myfile.js.php, just to keep it straight in my head what the file actually is.

Comment: That still won't work as the local variables defined in the PHP page are not available in the (PHP-generated) JavaScript. These are generated by two completely stand-alone HTTP requests, and either of them may be cached at any time. The only reliable way would be to **inline** the JavaScript code pulling the PHP variables into JS variables *inside* the PHP page itself.

Comment: This won't solve the problem. PHP variables don't carry over from one script to another, so all those variables will not be filled in when he loads `calceve.php`.

Comment: I have never had a problem defining variables on a page and the linked javascript file reading those variables. He is generating javascript code using PHP. As long as the server knows to use PHP, it can be done.

Comment: I believe it would be much safer to inline the JS or define and use the php vars in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by taking all the javascript code and moving it inside the  tag on the php page. not sure why this fixes it exactly but it works. I did also move the window.onload so the var are first